# eclipse c++ in ubuntu

Tags: eclipse-cdt

I was trying to run following code in eclipse in ubuntu 12.04 but It keeps giving me error. could you please tell me why this is happening ? Thanks.

```
   #include <iostream>
   using namespace std;

  int main()
  {
  cout << "Hello World!" << endl;
  return 0;
  }
```

Symbol 'std' could not be resolved
 Symbol 'cout' could not be resolved
 Symbol 'endl' could not be resolved

Comment: But it compiles the code OK and the code runs?  It's most likely the toolchain not set-up correctly within eclipse.

Comment: When I click "build project" under project in the menu bar, it gives me this problem.. So It doesn't run.. Do I need to change something in eclipse ? Thanks.

Comment: Try it from the command line first to make sure all necessary packages are installed.

Comment: I am sorry.. I have never used C++ in command line.. Thanks..

Comment: `g++ -o myprog myprog.cpp`  (where myprog.cpp is the name of the source file you posted).

Comment: maby it is for link prolebm so try this : ln -s /usr/bin/g++-4.6 /usr/bin/g++

Answer (score 5):

This is the C++ parser of Eclipse who can't find the symbols.

You could add the config to your already created project but it can be painful. So simply create a new C++ project :

File > New > C++ Project

Then :

Pick the type of project you want, like "Executable > Empty Project" (or maybe "Makefile Project > Empty Project") and make sure to select *Linux GCC* in the Toolchains. This will add all the default includes in the configuration so that the C++ parser finds everything. Click Finish, paste your code in a C++ file and enjoy.

For information, you can see these include paths in the Project Properties > C/C++ General > Paths and Symbols > Includes > GNU C++.

Comment: if you are sure you have all the path set correctly, create new project this makes  Eclipse pick up all the necessary setting,